# TextBox on a form is acting weird

Tags: c#, winforms, controls, textbox

I had a main form. I created a child form that is instantiated by this parent form. I have some textbox, buttons and a progress bar on that child form. When I create that form and show it, the textbox's in that form (child) becomes kind of transparent. When I click on them to write something, my child form becomes inactive and the window behind becomes active. Its also transparent and I can see the background. It's like the textboxes have created holes in that form.

Other controls on that form are working fine.

Here is the code I wrote to show the child form

```
TransferFile_Form sendFile = new TransferFile_Form();            
sendFile.Show(this);
```

and here is the codebehind for one of those textboxes:

```
this.txt_file.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(139, 45);
this.txt_file.Name = "txt_file";
this.txt_file.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(320, 21);
this.txt_file.TabIndex = 2;
```

There is nothing else I am doing. When I used tabs, I can select the textbox and write on it.

Anyone aware of what might have gone wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you happen to set the [`TransparencyKey`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.transparencykey.aspx) property of the form to the same color as the background color of the `TextBox` controls? That would make anything on the form having that color to be transparent and behave as if there was a "hole" there, like you describe.

Comment: Indeed it was. I somehow selected a value for it when checking different properties.

Thanks.